# List all existing npm packages in remote registry

Tags: npm, artifactory, npx, npm-registry

There's our internal deployed registry (JFrog Artifactory). And there we have an NPM registry with repo npm-virtual, which can be accessed for requests by a link `https://artifactory.xyz.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual`

I wonder, is there an npm/npx/... bash command, that can help me get the list of every package, that we contain in our registry?

`npx npm-registry-fetch ls --registry=https://artifactory.xyz.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual`

resulted with:
`npm ERR! could not determine executable to run`

Every other command I've found requires a reference to exact package that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get all packages is to use the [JFrog CLI](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/jfrog-cli) [search](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/searching-files) command:

1. Configure your Artifactory server:

```bash
jf c add
```

2. Run the search command:

```bash
jf rt s "npm-virtual/*.tgz"
```

Results:

```json
[
  {
    "path": "npm-remote-cache/mri/-/mri-1.2.0.tgz",
    "type": "file",
    "size": 4448,
    "created": "2022-12-06T07:30:45.533Z",
    "modified": "2021-09-12T22:35:55.000Z",
    "sha1": "6721480fec2a11a4889861115a48b6cbe7cc8f0b",
    "sha256": "9e383990963c167baa471cc928a02eb1768ee2ffabf8117082a09b5213f9a575",
    "md5": "3447f63dcd06670e37015dddee114918",
    "props": {
      "artifactory.internal.etag": [
        "\"3447f63dcd06670e37015dddee114918\""
      ],
      "artifactory.licenses": [
        "MIT"
      ],
      "npm.description": [
        "quickly scan for cli flags and arguments"
      ],
      "npm.keywords": [
        "[\"argv\",\"arguments\",\"cli\",\"minimist\",\"options\",\"optimist\",\"parser\",\"args\"]"
      ],
      "npm.name": [
        "mri"
      ],
      "npm.version": [
        "1.2.0"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "path": "npm-remote-cache/dequal/-/dequal-2.0.3.tgz",
    "type": "file",
    "size": 4286,
    "created": "2022-12-06T07:30:45.560Z",
    "modified": "2022-07-11T23:29:06.000Z",
    "sha1": "2644214f1997d39ed0ee0ece72335490a7ac67be",
    "sha256": "941d90d6629878167d10d2a05d8c6df8f8fa13acc826616abb49db63ac6a5c35",
    "md5": "65cb9dc71fa9ec2c942ad60fe62c3b37",
    "props": {
      "artifactory.internal.etag": [
        "\"65cb9dc71fa9ec2c942ad60fe62c3b37\""
      ],
      "artifactory.licenses": [
        "MIT"
      ],
      "npm.description": [
        "a tiny (304b to 489b) utility for check for deep equality"
      ],
      "npm.keywords": [
        "[\"deep\",\"deep-equal\",\"equality\"]"
      ],
      "npm.name": [
        "dequal"
      ],
      "npm.version": [
        "2.0.3"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Combining with `jq`:

```bash
jf rt s "npm-virtual/*.tgz" | jq '.[] | .path'
```

Results:

```
"npm-remote-cache/mri/-/mri-1.2.0.tgz"
"npm-remote-cache/dequal/-/dequal-2.0.3.tgz"
"npm-remote-cache/vfile-message/-/vfile-message-3.1.3.tgz"
"npm-remote-cache/unist-util-is/-/unist-util-is-5.1.1.tgz"
"npm-remote-cache/trough/-/trough-2.1.0.tgz"
"npm-remote-cache/unist-util-generated/-/unist-util-generated-2.0.0.tgz"
"npm-remote-cache/micromark-factory-label/-/micromark-factory-label-1.0.2.tgz"
"npm-remote-cache/micromark-util-sanitize-uri/-/micromark-util-sanitize-uri-1.1.0.tgz"
"npm-remote-cache/unist-util-stringify-position/-/unist-util-stringify-position-3.0.2.tgz"
"npm-remote-cache/micromark-util-encode/-/micromark-util-encode-1.0.1.tgz"
"npm-remote-cache/is-hexadecimal/-/is-hexadecimal-1.0.4.tgz"
```

Read more about it here:

1. [npm Packages with JFrog CLI](https://jfrog.com/blog/npm-flies-with-jfrog-cli/)
2. [Building Npm Packages Using the Npm Client](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/building-npm-packages-using-the-npm-client)
3. [Install JFrog CLI](https://jfrog.com/getcli)